# It Has A Child card - do you stay in Tokyo?

Tags: king-of-tokyo

It Has A Child states

> If you are eliminated discard all your cards and lose all your [Star], Heal to  10 [Heart] and start again.

If somebody with this card is in Tokyo and they are eliminated, do they remain in Tokyo when they start again?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*It Has a Child* doesn't prevent you from being eliminated. If it did, it would be phrased

> If you would be eliminated, instead ...

instead of

> If you are eliminated, ...

This means that other effects that occur on elimination still occur. Specifically,

> If you are eliminated by an attack on Tokyo, the Monster who attacked you automatically takes control of Tokyo.
>
> Warning: A Discard card that deals damage to you is not an attack.
>
> If you are eliminated by such a card (Discard card), nobody takes your place, and Tokyo becomes unoccupied.

What it does is allow is for you to join the game with a fresh character. As usual, players start the game outside of Tokyo.

---

By the way, BGG [arrived](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/681926/it-has-child) at the same conclusion.

Answer (score 2):

There is a thread on [board game geek](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/681926/it-has-child)  that says you lose Tokyo and the person who eliminated you takes your place, or if you were eliminated by a card no one takes your place.

> "If you are eliminated by an attack on Tokyo, the Monster who attacked you automatically takes control of Tokyo." and "If you are eliminated by such a card (Discard card), nobody takes your place, and Tokyo becomes unoccupied."